# Como posso criptografar um texto de entrada pelo usuario?esta dando erro

Tags: python, python-3.x, criptografia

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa

#gerando a chave privada
private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend()
)
#gerando chave publica
public_key = private_key.public_key()

senha_cripto = str(input("Senha para criptografar:")).strip()

while senha_cripto != 'batata':
    print("Senha incorreta, tente novamente!")
    senha_cripto = str(input("Senha para criptografar:")).strip()
    if senha_cripto == 'batata':
        break;

mensagem = str(input("escreva uma mensagem:"))




texto_cifrado = public_key.encrypt(
    mensagem,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),
        label=None
    )
)
print(texto_cifrado)


normaltext = private_key.decrypt(
    mensagem,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),
        label=None
    )
)

print(normaltext)
```

Comment: Nathalia onde está o erro? Por favor poste o LOG para ficar mais fácil de auxiliarmos

Comment: ola, quando eu coloco mensagem = b'o que vai ser criptografado ele da certo'

Comment: mas quando coloco pra pessoa entrar o texto como mensagem = str(input("escreva uma mensagem:")) ele da erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A criptografia só funciona com `bytes`. É isso que significa a letra `b` no início da literal. Ao ler uma string do usuário ela vem em `str`, e você precisa converter para `bytes` para poder criptografar.

Para fazer essa codificação use o método `encode()` passando uma codificação (a mais comum é a `utf-8` que consegue encodificar todos os caracteres unicode, sem gastar muito espaço):

```
mensagem = input("escreva uma mensagem:")
bytes_mensagem = mensagem.encode('utf-8') 
...
texto_cifrado = public_key.encrypt(bytes_mensagem, ...)
```

Da mesma forma, depois de criptografar a biblioteca vai te retornar bytes. Você precisa decodificar a string de volta:

```
bytes_mensagem = private_key.decrypt(....)
normaltext = bytes_mensage.decode('utf-8')
print(normaltext)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta já foi respondida, porém esse trecho do seu código pode ser melhorado.

```
while senha_cripto != 'batata':
    print("Senha incorreta, tente novamente!")
    senha_cripto = str(input("Senha para criptografar:")).strip()
    if senha_cripto == 'batata':
        break;
```

para:

```
from hashlib import sha256
while sha256(senha_cripto.encode()).hexdigest() != 'f4610aa514477222afac2b77f971d069780ca2846f375849f3dfa3c0047ebbd1':
    print("Senha incorreta, tente novamente!")
    senha_cripto = str(input("Senha para criptografar:")).strip()
```

E não presisa desse codigo.

```
if senha_cripto == 'batata':
    break;
```

Simplesmente porque, não é um laço infinito `while(True)`, porque ele vai ser interrompido logo quando vc acerta a senha.

Comment: [Nunca deve usar `!=` ou `== ` para comparações criptográficas](https://rdist.root.org/2009/05/28/timing-attack-in-google-keyczar-library/). Além de claro, o SHA256 não foi feito para senhas. Acho que se fosse para melhorar não iria fazer isso.

Comment: Concordo! porém nesse caso seria melhor do que deixa texto simples.